# How do you repair items?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I didn't realize that this game has durability (but of course it has durability), so I was mid-battle with a bear when it popped up the helpful tooltip that my sword was in bad shape and I should repair it. Somehow I didn't die.

The helpful tooltip, however, failed to mention how on earth I should accomplish that. How exactly do I repair my damaged sword?

Answer (score 23):

You can repair damaged items in one of two ways:

#### Repairs (NPC):

At any Smith, navigate to the Repair menu (part of the "Craft something for me?" options, between Crafting and Remove Upgrade).

[image: Witcher 3 Repair Menu]
You can then either repair all of your damaged items (which can potentially be expensive) or repair a single item by selecting it and pressing <kbd>E</kbd> (or the platform equivalent).

[An example video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gllEGJ30IU)

#### Repairs (Kits):

Purchase, loot, or otherwise acquire a Weapon Repair Kit. Select it in the Inventory, and apply it to the weapon you wish to repair.

[image: Selection of Repair Kits]

This is equally applicable to Armor Repair Kits, which function identically (but for use on Armor).

[An example video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxBISfuWH6c)

Repair Kits come in 3 levels, which simply repair *more* (a higher percentage) of an items durability:

- Amateur's +15%
- Journeyman +40%
- Master's +90%

Comment: The much more complete answer than mine. +1 for you and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With repair kits you have the big advantage, that you can repair your weapons wherever you are. You don't have to travel and find a weapon smith with the necessary skill for your damaged weapon.

There are (at least) 3 different repair kits. The difference is the amount of % of repair they do per use. Another important thing: You need a Repair Kit Diagram for each type before you can buy such kits from vendors.

Just to let you know: You also need to repair your armor from time to time.

Comment: If I remember correctly (might not), repair isn't linked to the Smith ranking system.

Comment: You do not need the diagrams to purchase or loot the repair kits

Comment: @Jeeva: Every Smith can repair every weapon? Are you sure? (Is this one of the latest patch changes?) @ Dallium: In one of the first versions of the game, I wasn't able to buy the repair kits without the diagrams. (Is this one of the latest patch changes?)

Comment: I'm reasonably sure. I was repairing even my highest level crafted Witcher gear at the Journeyman blacksmiths in the center of Novigrad with no issue, from the earliest versions. Additionally, I think @Dallium is right about the kits, as I left purchasing BPs very late due to the ease of finding high level kits.

Comment: You can only notify one user per comment, Peter. That said, the inventory of all shop keepers changes as you level increases. In my first (release day) play through, I never bought the recipes because I didn't see the point, I was swimming in (IMHO useless) repair kits anyway.