# What does it mean when on the left side I see armour with 2 red swords?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I am very confused and I want to know what it means, but also if it means like 'broken swords', how and where can I fix them?

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful, if you can provide one.

Answer (score 5):

- **It indeed means both your swords are damaged**.

  For reference, here is a cropped screenshot of a moment during gameplay where the silver sword (left sword icon, with the typical angled cross guard) and all armour except for the gauntlets are damaged:

  [image]

  Using weapons and gear will slowly decrease their condition (hitting objects and receiving hits, respectively), and lower their stats, as indicated in red negative values on the item's description in your inventory. You can keep using the items in this state, but their ineffectiveness will keep increasing.
  The icons on your HUD show up as red when the condition of the item drops to or below 50%.
- As for **repairing these items**, there's an existing Q&A [here on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235601/how-do-you-repair-items/235645) which handles that aspect.

Comment: Apparently bisecting creatures diagonally through ribs & spine is rough on a blade's edge.  Who'da thunk?

Answer (score 0):

It means they are damaged and less effective. Your armour will also deteriorate and become less effective. Best to carry some repair kits available from armourers and blacksmiths. You use them in your inventory by dragging them onto the damaged equipment.

Comment: Hi Karl, welcome to Arqade! Please note that this doesn't add anything new to the existing answer.